# Autofocus only works once

Tags: angular, typescript

When the Input is clicked, autofocus works only on the first instance - therefore the 'list-formatter' (autocompleListFormatter) is initiated only once.

[image: **Demo**]

Is there a simple solution to make 'autofocus' focus more than one time?

**dropdown.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="">
  <div class="form-style">
    <input
      autofocus
      [list-formatter]="autocompleListFormatter"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      ngui-auto-complete
      formControlName="costCenter"
      [source]="dropdownData"
      value-property-name="id"
      display-property-name="name"
      [(ngModel)]="value"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

**dropdown.component.ts**

```
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit, AgEditorComponent {
  @Input() name: String;

  public dropdownData = ColumnData[0].cellEditorParams.values;
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public selected;
  value: any;
  oldValue: any;
  params: any;
  public container;
  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

// ****DROPDOWN****** //
  autocompleListFormatter = (data: any) => {
    let html = `<span>${data.name}</span>`;
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  };

  refresh(params: ICellEditorParams) {
    this.params.api.refreshCells();
    return true;
  }

  getValue(): any {
    if (this.value === '') {
      this.value = this.oldValue;
    }
    return this.value;
  }

  agInit(params: ICellEditorParams) {
    this.value = params.value;
    this.oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    return this.value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.builder.group({
      costCenter: ''
    });
  }
}
```

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angu1ar)

Update: I have read that it is useful to implement an [auto-focus directive](https://www.codementor.io/yomateo/auto-focus-with-angular-7-the-directive-osfcl7rrv). I have added the directive to my code but cannot get it to function correctly

Comment: perhaps what happens is that you want to focus each time the dropdown is shown but you render it only once. maybe you need to do it on another event, like click element and/or put it in other [lifecycle event](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)?

Comment: Thanks @akkonrad I did think that at first but you will see from the gif, on the second instance, it does not focus so I have to click the input again for the dropdown to appear

Comment: can you provide workable stackblitz example?

Comment: I have added the STACKBLITZ, please see above. @akkonrad

Comment: Unfortunately, on the Stackblitz I receive an error `Error: No component factory found for DropdownComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?` when clicking on the one of the cells

Comment: @akkonrad since the Stackblitz is not working I have added the code to bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/ross2711/dropdown.git

Comment: you can do this. Keep track of selected item and focus it manually when dropdown close.

Comment: I hope this will work fro you check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xqrfgj 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this can be done without directive just get input elemnt refrence and run `focus` method

*template*

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="">
  <div class="form-style">
    <input
      defFocus
      [list-formatter]="autocompleListFormatter"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      ngui-auto-complete
      formControlName="costCenter"
      [source]="dropdownData"
      value-property-name="id"
      display-property-name="name"
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      #agInput
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

*component*

```
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit, AgEditorComponent {

  @Input() name: String;
  @ViewChild('agInput', { static: true}) public elm: ElementRef;

  ....

  setFocus() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.setFocus();
     }, 500);
   }
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xqrfgj)

check my answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436328/getting-focus-on-buttons-p-toast-primeng-modal/57582169#57582169) where I create a custom directive to fix focus problem.

Comment: Thanks @malbarmawi. I have added the directive and declared it in my app.module but dont seem to be getting the console.log outputs within ngAfterViewInit(){}. Is there anywhere else I should be declaring this? https://bitbucket.org/ross2711/dropdown/src/master/

Comment: I couldn't test you demo but I have update my answer by create a view query to that input element and call it at the time you want like when the data come refresh , you are control this

Comment: I have pull your project and tested it seem you need to call focuse after half of second will make it work

Comment: Thanks @malbarmawi, it works well. Last question - is there any way to do this without using timeout? If not, why is the timeout needed?

Comment: you can replace timeout block with ` Promise.resolve().then(() =>this.setFocus())`

Comment: if you run the focus without any delay the ui will not working any more maybe because the autocomplete or others thing is still not fully initialized,this way we will schedul the method `()=> this.setFocus()` at the time nothing is running mean everything finish initializing